# how to handle multiple submit buttons in form cakephp3

Tags: cakephp-3.0, form-submit

I have just started learning cakephp3, so please excuse me for anything wrong.

So I have one form in which I am collecting data, I want to have two submit buttons. One submit button will return to the index page, and another submit button will re-direct me to some other action.

But how to know in controller that which submit button has been clicked?

here is my code

```
<?= $this->Form->create($User) ?>
    <fieldset>
        <legend><?= __('Add User') ?></legend>
        <?php
            echo $this->Form->control('first_name');
            echo $this->Form->control('last_name');
            echo $this->Form->control('status');
        ?>
    </fieldset>
    <?= $this->Form->submit(__('Save & Exit', array('name'=>'btn1'))) ?>
    <?= $this->Form->submit(__('Save & Add Educational Details', array('name'=>'btn2'))) ?>
                <?= $this->Form->end() ?>
```

in my controller i have written this

```
if(isset($this->request->data['btn1'])) {
                    return $this->redirect(['action' => 'index']);
} else  if(isset($this->request->data['btn2'])) {
            return $this->redirect(['controller' => 'educationQualifications', 'action' => 'add']);
}
```

but I am not able to get which button has been clicked..

Please tell how can I achieve this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Take a close look at the argument(s) that you are passing to the `submit()` method, you've placed the options array wrongly, you are passing them to the `__()` method.

Comment: @ndm Thank you it worked.. but i am confused as it is self generated code using cake bake all command.
What exactly do we mean when we say __() method. What does it mean ?

Comment: If that is bake generated code, then you are either using custom bake templates, as the default bake templates do neither generate multiple buttons, nor do they generate options for `submit()`, especially not with old < PHP 5.4 style arrays, or you've modified the results. `__()` is a [**translation**](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/core-libraries/internationalization-and-localization.html) method.

Answer (score 0):

What ever you did is right but a small mistake, You have to use **isset()** in **if** condition as **if** implicitly not check for **isset()**.  Check the correction below

```
if(isset($this->request->data['btn1'])) {
                    return $this->redirect(['action' => 'index']);
} else  if(isset($this->request->data['btn2'])) {
            return $this->redirect(['controller' => 'educationQualifications', 'action' => 'add']);
}
```

Or you can try this, you have to give the same name for the buttons.

```
In your view
<?= $this->Form->submit(('Save & Exit'), array('name'=>'btn')) ?>
<?= $this->Form->submit(('Save & Add Educational Details'), array('name'=>'btn')) ?>

In your controller
if($this->request->data['btn']=='Save & Exit') {
                    return $this->redirect(['action' => 'index']);
} else  if($this->request->data['btn']=='Save & Add Educational Details')) {
            return $this->redirect(['controller' => 'educationQualifications', 'action' => 'add']);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for reply. but that was not the issue.. i had written isset in the original code but somehow it got skipped here. @ndm figured out it correctly